# How to apply javascript on <asp:Buttonfield>?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to apply javascript on `asp:buttonfield` , when click on button then display message. 
Like Delete Button confirm message.

Answer (score 2):

asp:ButtonField> tag does not have an OnClientClick.

Replace with Templated button

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function function()
   {
       return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this?");
   }
</script>

...

<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="button" runat="server"
        OnClientClick="return function();" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I have <asp:Buttonfield>. So <asp:Buttonfield> tag is not support  OnClientClick attribute. Any Solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your page load, you could add

```
button.Attributes.Add("onclick", "confirm('are you sure? blah!')");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a fairly simple way of doing this when working with jQuery which meant I could still use an asp:boundbutton

Apply a CssClass of 'btn-remove' to the bound button (in this case) then add the following jQuery script

```
    $(function () {
        $('.btn-remove a').attr('onclick', 'return confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this?\')');
    });
```